# Trying to use WEEKDAY function to make a column always return a Friday date, based off another date column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, date

So far I have this, anyone know why it isn't working??

Goal is to return the first Friday after the [Est. Stock Date].

```
=IF(WEEKDAY("[Est. Stock Date]"=1,[Est. Stock Date]+5,IF(WEEKDAY("[Est. Stock Date]"=2,[Est. Stock Date]+4,IF(WEEKDAY("[Est. Stock Date]"=3,[Est. Stock Date]+3,IF(WEEKDAY("[Est. Stock Date]"=4,[Est. Stock Date]+2,IF(WEEKDAY("[Est. Stock Date]"=5,[Est. Stock Date]+1,IF(WEEKDAY("[Est. Stock Date]"=6,[Est. Stock Date],IF(WEEKDAY("[Est. Stock Date]"=7,[Est. Stock Date]+6,)))))))&IF([Est. Stock Date]="","",)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting what you've tried. Can you please edit your question and specify your requirements? "return a Friday" doesn't quite cut it. Any Friday? The first Friday before the  date in question? The first Friday after the date in question?

Comment: @teylyn Actually what I'm after is the first Friday 7 weeks after the date in the [Est Stock Date] column. I've been trying to just get the first Friday to work and was then planning on adding 7 weeks to that.

Comment: As I said: Please edit your question and specify your requirements. Nobody wants to read through all the comments to learn what you are really after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the syntax of your formula is correct. Try something like this:

```
=IF(IsBlank([Est. Stock Date]),"",IF(WEEKDAY([Est. Stock Date])=1,[Est. Stock Date]+5,IF(WEEKDAY([Est. Stock Date])=2,[Est. Stock Date]+4,IF(WEEKDAY([Est. Stock Date])=3,[Est. Stock Date]+3,IF(WEEKDAY([Est. Stock Date])=4,[Est. Stock Date]+2,IF(WEEKDAY([Est. Stock Date])=5,[Est. Stock Date]+1,IF(WEEKDAY([Est. Stock Date])=6,[Est. Stock Date],IF(WEEKDAY([Est. Stock Date])=7,[Est. Stock Date]+6)))))))+49)
```